# android-launch external browser and come back to the app with back button

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have one `Activity` with multiple dynamically generated `Fragments` in my android app. the user can click on a button which will open a website in the external browser (e.g google chrome). then when the user clicks the back button, I want he to come back to where he was in my app, but the current behavior is that the system closes the google chrome and navigates to home screen!

I'm confused whether I must save everything in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` or should think about using flags while launching browser activity or what?!

p.s. I have 2 `Activities` in my app. the launcher one is a simple splash activity with `noHistory` set to `true` and another `Activity` which contains everything, including all fragments

Comment: This should just work out of the box. Please post your manifest in your question and also post the code you use to launch the browser.

Comment: yes! the problem was the SplashActivity and its noHistory attribute. just removed the SplashActivity and everything worked

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look into ChromeCustomTabs (now in androidX called Browser).
Just add this dependency: `implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"`

You can open an URL simply with:
`CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().launchUrl(/* context */, /* url as Uri */)`
This supports the back press :)

If you don't use androidX in your project, you can use the "old version" ChromeCustomTabs instead. It works in a similar way, though I would recommend migrating to androidX ([as explained in this article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate))

Comment: many thanks. but what if I want to open `phone app` and then come back to my app with back button? I mean think of the browser just as an example

Comment: so you mean: your app is open -> user goes to the homescreen -> opens the phone app -> presses back -> he will land on the homescreen.
but you want him to land in your app again? I don't think that this is possible

Comment: no, I mean when he clicks on a button in my app, I'll open phone app, and then I want he to come back where he was in my app with back button

Comment: Ah ok. So I have just created a new project which just calls a number on button click and if the call ends or if I press back I will get back to the App as expected. Inside onClick I just do this: 
                `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "0000"));
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: thanks for your test! the problem was the SplashActivity and its noHistory attribute. just removed the SplashActivity and everything worked

Comment: Cool. Glad you were able to find the problem. Please provide an answer to your question and accept that answer. It will get the question off the list of unanswered questions and may help others who have a similar problem.